# Rename multiple file's before upload php Error Upload only single file

Tags: php

I'm trying to rename each file before uploading it to the directory. First for loop is working perfectly fine and shows all file name correct in $success array but the issue is upload in the directory only single file. here is my code down below.

Sorry for my Bad English hope you understand well my point.

```
$success = array();
$failed = array();
$allowed = array('pdf','png','jpg','gif');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    for ($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']); $i++) { 
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i])){
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];

            $temp = explode('.',$_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
            $extension = end($temp);
            $targetfolder = "uploads/";
            $newname="MTI_123654";
            $filenamee = $newname . '.' . $extension;

            if(in_array($ext, $allowed)){
                // $path = "uploads/".$filename;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],  $targetfolder .$filenamee);
                $success[] = $filenamee;
            }else{
                $failed[] = $filename;
            }
        }
    }
    $results = array(
        'success'=>$success,
        'failed'=>$failed
    );
echo json_encode($results);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably just overwriting the same file over and over again, because of this code:

```
        $newname="MTI_123654";
        $filenamee = $newname . '.' . $extension;
```

if you dynamicly set the new filename it should probably work. You could test like this:

```
        $newname="MTI_123654". $i;
        $filenamee = $newname . '.' . $extension;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you first of all .. some times your brain is stuck on focusing too much ..

Comment: Yeah it happens to the best of us sometimes :D